# What does this obfuscated C example do?

Tags: c

I read this hoax: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/unix-hoax.html

And it contains some obfuscated C code which is:

```
for(;P("\n"),R--;P("|"))for(e=C;e--;P("_"+(*u++/8)%2))P("| "+(*u/4)%2);
```

I added the minimum code to make it work, and it ended this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define P(...)  printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define C   (7)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto    R;
    auto    e;
    auto    *u;

    R   = 5;

    for(;P("\n"),R--;P("|"))for(e=C;e--;P("_"+(*u++/8)%2))P("| "+(*u/4)%2);
}
```

After compiling and checking that it works (and prints something), I wrote the code with some less obfuscation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C   (7)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto    R;
    auto    e;
    auto    *u;

    R   = 5;


    while(R) {
        /* for1: param 2.1 */
        printf("\n");
        /* for1: param 2.2 */
        R--;

        for(e = C; e; ) {
            /* for2: param 2 */
            e--;

            printf("| " + (*u / 4) % 2);

            /* for2: param 3 */
            printf("_" + (*u++ / 8) % 2);
        }

        /* for1: param 3 */
        printf("|");

    }
    /* for1: param 2.1 */
    printf("\n");
}
```

After compiling like this:  `$ gcc tst.c -o tst`  I see two different outputs (Undefined behaviour I suppose):

```
$ ./tst 

| _| _ _ | _| _ |
 |    | _ |
 _  _ | _ | _|
  _ | _   |
 _ |  | _ | |
$ ./tst 

| _| _|  | _| __|
 |  | _ | _ |
|  |   | _|
   | _ |
|  _  _|
```

So now to the point:  What the hell does this do?

```
printf("| " + (*u / 4) % 2)
```

or even worse:

```
printf("_" + (*u++ / 8) % 2)
```

Comment: Your `u` is uninitialised.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the _minimum_.  For the same reason I declared the variables as auto and not int.  The code says it works, so it is the code's fault, not mine.

Comment: The text only mentions that this line does not have syntactical errors. It doesn't make any statements about being complete or useful code.

Comment: And now you know why most people try to write code that is easily understood and very readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u` is not initialized in the original code or your additions. Presuming it had a proper value, then, if `*u` is not negative:

```
"| " + (*u / 4) % 2
```

is a pointer to the character `'|'` or `' '` according to whether `*u` is 0-3 or 4-7 modulo 8. In effect, `printf` is passed either `"| "` or `" "`. Thus, the `printf` will print either “| ” or “ ”.

And:

```
"_" + (*u++ / 8) % 2
```

is a pointer to either the `'_'` or the null character that terminates the string according to whether `*u` is 0-7 or 8-15 modulo 8, before the increment. Thus, the `printf` will print either “_” or nothing.

Comment: Is it defined behaviour to use pointer arithmetics like this on a string literal?
If so, where in the standard is that?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes, why should this be undefined? As long as there are no write accesses, there is nothing special with a string literal. You could also use a `char[]` with the very same effect.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: Per C 2018 6.4.5 6, a string literal in source text is used to initialize an array of static storage duration. Then it is just the array, and the usual rules for arrays apply. When used in an expression (other than as the operand of `sizeof` or of unary `&` or as an initializer for an array), it is converted to a pointer to its first element, and then ordinary pointer arithmetic works.

Answer (score 2):

The line comes from a submission to the [International Obfuscated C Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/). It belongs to the winning entry *shapiro* [from 1985](https://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1985). Note that there is another winning entry called "shapiro" from 1994.

In its intended context the line participates in printing a maze.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("| " + (*u / 4) % 2)
```

it will write ("| " + 0) = "| ", or ("| " + 1) = " ", depending on the value of `(*u / 4) % 2` being 0 or 1

the expression just return the address of "| " or that address more 1

it is similar for the other print